# No video from video card or onboard video in new pc build

Tags: motherboard

I'm working on building a custom PC, and I've run into a problem. I have an ASRock B75 Pro 3 motherboard and a Nvidia GeForce GTX 660 video card.
After I installed everything (correctly, as far as I know, but I could be wrong, since this is my first build), including the video card. When I powered it on, with an HDMI cable from the monitor to the video card I didn't get any display. Thinking it might be an issue with the video card, I pulled out the video card and plugged in a VGA cable to the onboard VGA port, and I still can't see anything. I reset my CMOS, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my RAM
Any ideas?

I checked the CPU, and there aren't any bent pins. Everything seems to be receiving power, all the fans are running, (the video card fans, the CPU fan, and the case fans), and the power button LED works

Comment: Did you find the check what the video adapter settings are in the bios?  It should tell you what video device it will use.  Might be a place to start.

Comment: @Damon: That would be pretty hard to do if the system is not outputting anything over integrated or discrete graphics. Does the system beep at all when you start it? [Beep codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm) are a lost art, it used to be you could tell immediately what the problem was by the number and duration of beeps - but these days a lot of systems do not even have PC speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined that the motherboard is defective. It shows all the signs of that being the case, and looking around on the internet, others have had similar issues with this model.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check with larger video cards is to make sure they have adequate power. Glad you figured it out though